# Are there any task/job scheduler as a cloud service?

Tags: cloud, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

My application need a cloud service that will schedule tasks at specific time which will trigger an API call with given parameters. It will be better if the cloud service capable to add many task(~2million/hour) for the next 7 day. I already searched it, but unable to find one. It's okay if it's on enterprise plan.